# adding a UILabel as subview of UIButton doesn't trigger button action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UIButton` and I am adding a subview to the `UIButton` which is a `UILabel`. When I tap on the `UILabel` the action of the button doesn't get triggered. Is there an easy fix so that the touch event gets passed to the `UIButton` when the `UILabel` is tapped?
I am thinking of adding a gesture recognizer to the `UILabel` which then triggers the action of the `UIButton`, not sure if there's a much more simpler way.

Comment: How did you add your label, in code or IB? And, why are you adding a label -- a button already has a titleLabel, why add another one?

Comment: post the code you used to add that label

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably just disable user interaction to your label.

```
_yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *firstButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [firstButton setTitle:@"first" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    firstButton.frame=CGRectMake(40, 70, 80, 80);
    [firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:firstButton];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    label.text=@"hai";
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [firstButton addSubview:label];

}

-(void)firstButtonClicked {
    NSLog(@"first");
}
```